# Java switch statements bypasses all cases and even default

Tags: java, android

I'm working with android gestures. The switch statement seems right, but does not do anything. This is the code from my activity. Anybody see an issue? Thanks.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    mGestureCompat.onTouchEvent(event);

    final int action = event.getActionMasked();
    switch (action)
    {
        case 0://MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;                          //breakpoint here - never triggered
        case 3://MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;                          //breakpoint here - never triggered
        case 2://MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;                          //breakpoint here - never triggered
        case 1://MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;                          //breakpoint here - never triggered
        case 4://MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
            break;                          //breakpoint here - never triggered
        default:
            break;                          //breakpoint here - never triggered
    }
    return true;                            //breakpoint here - triggered every time
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add a bunch of log statements? I suspect that switch block in optimized away because it doesn't do anything. Also try to log `action`, maybe it has yet another value?

Comment: add a breakpoint to switch(action) what is the value of action?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on breakpoints for that, especially since every `case` is empty. Put log prints in your `case`s.

Comment: Put breakpoint at action variable assignment and check value. May be it is null. Second thing, why are you calling onTouchEvent from event body. I am not android developer but does not seem okay.

Comment: What is your issue? Wanna return something other than True? Your code just return true

Comment: *"...  but does not do anything."* ... Well, that's exactly what you coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe compiling optimization completely eliminates that, as there is practically nothing relevant there. 
Have you tried putting some real code under each case, or at least under the default?

Comment: Thanks. The debugger doesn't stop at the break statement. It does at a functional statement.

Answer (score 0):

try to test the touches by putting a toast message at each case and check the message is showing the right action or no.